# Vue router button not clickable because setup is incorrect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to setup Vue router for the first time and I'm running into trouble.

#### router/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Services from '../components/Services'
import App from '../app'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'App',
      component: App
    },
    {
      path: '/services',
      name: 'Services',
      component: Services
    }
  ]
})
```

#### app.vue

```
<template>
  <div id='app'>
    <Navigation></Navigation>

    <div class="Site-content">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>

    <Footer></Footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Services from "../javascript/components/Services";
  import Footer from "../javascript/components/Footer";
  import Navigation from "../javascript/components/Navigation";

  export default {
    components: {
      Footer,
      Navigation,
      Services
    },

    data: function () {
      return {
        message: "Welcome to Ping Party From Vue!"
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

#### Navigation.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="navigation">
    <nav v-bind:class="active" v-on:click>
      <a href="#" class="home" v-on:click="makeActive('home')">Home</a>
      <a href="#" class="projects" v-on:click="makeActive('projects')">Projects</a>
      <router-link to="/services">Services</router-link>
      <a href="#" class="contact" v-on:click="makeActive('contact')">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Services from './Services'

  export default {
    data () {
      return { active: 'home' }
    },
    methods: {
      makeActive: function(item) {
        this.active = item;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

That `vue-router` option is not working in my navigation. It shows up on the page but it's not clickable and I'm getting this error in the console.

#### ERROR

```
Unknown custom element: <router-link> - did you register the component 
correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" 
option.

found in

---> <Navigation> at app/javascript/components/Navigation.vue
   <App> at app/javascript/app.vue
     <Root>

 Unknown custom element: <router-view> - did you register the component 
 correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" 
 option.

 found in

  ---> <App> at app/javascript/app.vue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to register your router with your Vue instance.
So in your

```
import router from './router'

new Vue({
    el: '#some-element'
    router,  // This line is important
    render: h => h(App) 
})
```

Comment: By importing the `router/index.js` script, this also executes the all important `Vue.use(Router)` line which registers the vue-router components like `<router-link>` and `<router-view>`

Comment: I added that line. And everything you y'all suggested is in place. I appreciate the help though. Any chance I didn't add vue-router correctly?

Comment: Did you make sure to `npm i --save vue-router` ?

Comment: @Bitwise you didn't have to add anything other than what's in this answer. If it's still not working, please add the relevant part to your question, ie the `new Vue(...)` part